# how to call a macro when a value provided by a DDE link change in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I tryed this code using SetLinkOnData to call a simple macro,"msg" in this case, I juste want to detecte the change of the value provided by a DDE link, but I receve this error : "compilation error, expected: end of statement"
It will be nice if someone indicate me how to use SetLinkOnData correctly or a mehode to detecte the change of the value given by the DDE Link, this is my code :

```
Sub UpDateDDE()
 Dim Mylink As String
 Dim Procedure As String
  Mylink = "MT4|BID!EURJPY"
  Procedure = "msg"
    With ThisWorkbook.SetLinkOnData Mylink Procedure
End Sub

Sub msg()
  MsgBox "new value detected!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
ThisWorkbook.SetLinkOnData Mylink, Procedure
```